# Android master template layout file?

Tags: java, android, xml, templates, layout

I have more than 5 activities `xml files` in `layout` folder
- `login_activity.xml`
- `user_profile_activity.xml`
- `product_activity.xml`
- `buy_activity.xml`
- `sell_activity.xml`

All layouts share the **same** `header` and `footer` views
So I create `header.xml` and  `footer.xml` then include them in each layout xml file

My problem
Now I need to update layout of ALL activities by adding new view in the middle
Currently solution to loop create `middle.xml` then include them in each!
As you can see, simple change added in multiple files!

Any other solution like [`Master Template`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system) concept
By using it, We can make a shared master template and each layout inherit this master template, then define ONLY its layout?

So the final picture will be something like that

**Subviews**
- `header.xml`
- `footer.xml`
- `middle.xml`

**Template**  will include `header`/`footer`/`middle` + contain *main empty div*
- `master_template.xml`

**Layouts**  will inherit `master_template.xml` + add impl to *main empty div*
- `login_activity.xml`
- `user_profile_activity.xml`
- `product_activity.xml`
- `buy_activity.xml`
- `sell_activity.xml`

Comment: you can declare a frame layout in the master file and inflate fragments dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FrameLayout and inflate it  dynamically however you want.

Checkout this one  : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout

Comment: seems solution by **inflate layouts dynamically** not by using **xml** only, thank you